# Hosted a static website using AWS s3 and mapped it with a Cloudflare subdomain getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have created a website and hosted it using Amazon s3 the endpoint of the site is as follows:
http://yallashop-website.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com which is accessible.

created CNAME with the name as yallashop.aybiz.com and target as the same endpoint excluding the http part but getting error as follows:

404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: yallashop.aybiz.com
RequestId: 4FF5C323ZN1EFEBX
HostId: ZwIm98qvoHNWdX664GNVApXGp8XuRWRgPDifEgBkHw2xureEZIPdeR38LlN2DLYxSXUYwE/fyQM=

Expected to view the website the same as the how it is viewed from the static website endpoint from the S3, my SSL/TLS setting is flexible on the Cloudflare. It is not accessible via https or http.

Comment: So to clarify, in CloudFlare for your domain aybiz.com, you set up a CNAME record with Name `yallashop` and Value `yallashop-website.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not accessible via that subdomain.